# Slick 3.1.1 sqlite java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, scala, sqlite, jdbc, slick

I'm trying to connect a sqlite database with Slick 3.1.1, using Macroid for Scala in Android develop.

Here is my code:

```
lazy val db = Database.forURL(
url = "jdbc:sqlite:" + getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "events.txt",
driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC")

dbSetupAction()
```

The dbSetupAction:

```
  def dbSetupAction() = {

    val initActions = DBIO.seq(
      events.schema.create
    )

    val futureInitActions = db.run(initActions)

    futureInitActions.onComplete {
      case Success(s) => Log.d("FICHEROS Success", s.toString)
      case Failure(ex) => Log.d("FICHEROS Failure", ex.toString)
    }


  }
```

Event class:

```
class Events(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, Int, Double)](tag, "EVENTS"){
  def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def eventType = column[Int]("EVENT_TYPE")
  def timeTag = column[Double]("TIMETAG")

  def * = (id, eventType, timeTag)

}
```

The output error i got is:

> D/FICHEROS Failure﹕ java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC

In my build.sbt, i've added:

```
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  aar("org.macroid" %% "macroid" % "2.0.0-M4"),
  aar("com.android.support" % "support-v4" % "21.0.0"),
  "org.xerial" % "sqlite-jdbc" % "3.8.11.2",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.1.1",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
proguardOptions += "-keep class org.sqlite.JDBC { *; }"
```